# force toolbar to arrange children rtl android?

Tags: android, toolbar, direction

I want to make my `Toolbar` always arrange it's children Right-To-Left `rtl` like that [image]

Comment: Are you looking to support it if the user supports  Arabic, Urdu, Hebrew languages?

Comment: My App will be only in Arabic

Comment: I have tried `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(view, direction)` but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for that problem.

First and thanks to @Eugene

```
<application
...
android:supportsRtl="true">
</application>
```

Second Force every `Activity` to use specific `Locale`

```
private void updateResources(String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        configuration.locale = locale;
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest.

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true">

</application>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code will change children arrange direction due locale change, that's not what I need, I need to make toolbar always like in image whatever the device locale is.